# How to test Bit-Banged communication's assembly routines

Tags: testing, assembly, embedded, microcontroller, uart

For one MCU I have written some assembly routines performing RX and TX of a proprietary protocol (UART-based) in a bit-bang fashion. How can I test them?

TX might be tested by sending data, and at the same time, with the help of a logic analyzer, checking that all the sampled timings are correct (manually or with some scripts).

RX on the other hand is more difficult. On one hand I can check if I'm receiving what someone else is sending, but on the other hand how do I know that the RX sampling is happening correctly (timing-wise)?
For example, my RX routine may return the correct data by sampling at the edge of the "bit window" instead of the middle.
I thought about toggling a "debug pin" to indicate when the sampling is actually happening, but this introduces delays in the sampling procedure, hence I wouldn't be testing my original routine.

Some things worth clarifying after reading comments:

- I know that hardware UART is better (it depends, though), but I can't use it. This is not a matter of "have you tried this ...?";
- I know how to do the bit banging (I have already written the assembly routines);
- I can't connect TX to RX because I'm only using 1 wire (the communication is half-duplex);
- **I'm asking how to test the RX sampling timings, not how to implement UART.**

Comment: Long time ago when I didn't have a UART but had a flexible serial port (with DMA), I configured the rx sample rate at 16(?)x the bitrate and then decoded those multiple bits into single bits, probably accounting for the shift / noting where bits change between 0 and 1. Do you really need to do something like this? Doesn't your UART do all of this for you, especially with start and stop bits that help to synchronize at each byte?

Comment: Here's a couple of documents describing the technique: [1](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra633c/spra633c.pdf), [2](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra661a/spra661a.pdf).

Comment: Also, you can connect rx and tx. If you can control them independently (e.g. run at slightly different rates or you can encode/send 15x bits while receiving/decoding 16x and vice versa), you can test synchronization.

Comment: For receive testing you just need to vary the rate of the transmission source to see if your receiver can accept transmission rates that are within tolerance (theoretical maximum of 5% for a typical 10-bit UART frame, but in practice less.)

Comment: tx is relatively easy if you can get the timing down.  Rx a bit harder, as you have to simulate a uart receiver when the start bit edge comes (you just assume it is)  measure to half a bit cell the sample there, and the next N bit cells based on the number of bits per character. then sample the stop bit mid bit cell, if it is not a stop bit start your state machine over looking for a start bit.  if you oversample you can see if there are any edges and if so then are they at the proper place within an acceptable margin, if not declare a framing error.

Comment: far better off using a uart, or getting an external i2c, or spi uart and you can big bang that all day long much fewer issues.

Comment: I know that hardware UART is better (it depends...) etc., but it's a different topic. I already have the routine doing the bit banging. My question is how to test the RX sampling timings. Independently on if I use 16x sampling, 3x sampling or 1x sampling. I just want to understand if there is a way to properly test this.

Comment: Please add to your question details of everything you have tried and researched, so people don’t bother wasting time with answers that they don’t know they should bother posting because you didn’t bother to add this detail _in the question_.

Comment: I have already added all the details. I've also suggested about toggling a debug pin, and I've explained why that isn't good as well. Which details am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought about toggling a "debug pin" to indicate when the sampling
>   is actually happening, but this introduces delays in the sampling
>   procedure, hence I wouldn't be testing my original routine.

Test with the instrumentation code, and then **leave the instrumentation** - or near-equivalent code that doesn't actually twiddle hardware - **in place**.

Comment: Great solution. I can have something like: #ifdef DEBUG_BITBANG
toggle_pin(...)
#else
nop nop nop.

The reason for nop(s) being that I don't want to pollute debug traces when I have to re-use the pin while debugging other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something to send data to the MCU, perhaps a second MCU. I've worked on similar code for both 6502 and Z80 for old 8 bit Atari peripherals. These are half duplex protocols, so whenever the device is idle, it's polling for a start bit. After detecting a start bit, it delays 1.5 bit times, then receives 8 bits, with 1 bit time between bits. Both receiving and sending of data routines are coded to get exact cycle counts for timing. These were old devices, and even the fastest bit rate was relatively slow at 19 microseconds per bit ~= 52600 baud.

---

The question has been updated. If the input and output instructions take the exact same time to run (cycle count), you could modify the receive code to transmit data to verify the bit time, and confirm exactly how fast the processor is running.

For the timing regarding sensing the start bit and doing a 1.5 bit time wait, you'd have to calculate the minimum and maximum number of cycles to sense the start bit. The maximum cycle count would be an input instruction that just misses the trailing edge of the start bit, the test instruction, and the loop back to the input, followed by another test and then a fall through the loop to continue the receive. The minimum cycle count would be an input that just barely catches the leading edge of the start bit, does a test, then falls through the loop. Then the remainder of the receive code needs to sample as close as possible to the middle of the data bit periods.

Here is example of code for a 4mhz Z80 that receives data at 19 microseconds == 76 cycles per data bit. The comments include the cycle count for each instruction. The ideal wait time for start bit to 1st data bit is 114 cycles. The min,max cycle time for the start bit loop is 20,50 cycles. An additional delay plus the input of the first data bit of 79 cycles is used so min,max cycle time to sense start to receive 1st data bit is 99,129 cycles, within the min,max bounds of 76,152 cycles. The remaining data bits are read at exactly 76 cycles per bit.

```
        LD      E,0             ;SET UP
;                               ;       START BIT TO DATA BIT=114
NRXF0:  LD      A,(FBS)         ;(13)   WAIT FOR START BIT
        AND     FBSRXD          ;(7)
        JP      NZ,NRXF0        ;(10)
;                               ;       NOTE: 20 MIN, 50 MAX, 35 AVG
        EX      (SP),HL         ;(19)   DELAY 
        EX      (SP),HL         ;(19)
        LD      A,(HL)          ;(7)
NRXF1:  LD      A,(HL)          ;(7)
        LD      A,(HL)          ;(7)
        LD      D,8             ;(7)    8 BITS PER BYTE
;                               ;       76 CYCLES PER DATA BIT
NRXF2:  LD      A,(FBS)         ;(13)   GET DATA BIT
        AND     FBSRXD          ;(7)
        ADD     A,0FFH          ;(7)
        RR      C               ;(8)
        PUSH    BC              ;(11)   DELAY
        POP     BC              ;(10)
        NOP                     ;(4)
        DEC     D               ;(4)    LP TIL BYTE DONE
        JR      NZ,NRXF2        ;(12/7)
        RET     NZ              ;(5)    DELAY
NRXF4:  LD      A,(FBS)         ;(13)   WAIT FOR NEXT START BIT
        AND     FBSRXD          ;(7)
        JP      NZ,NRXF4        ;(10)
;                               ;       START BIT TO DATA BIT=114
        LD      (HL),C          ;(7)    STORE BYTE
        LD      A,C             ;(4)    DO CKSUM
        ADD     A,E             ;(4)
        ADC     A,0             ;(7)
        LD      E,A             ;(4)
        INC     HL              ;(6)    ADV ADR
        DJNZ    NRXF1           ;(13/8) LP IF MORE BYTES
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have the routine doing this. I m wondering about how to test the sampling time.

Comment: @HBv6 - I updated my answer to include example code.  Once you've confirmed the cpu speed, you'll probably have to count cycles for each instruction used to receive data to get the timing correct.